# How to store return value of a function in a variable?

Tags: bash

I am pretty sure that this is a very basic question, but I am not able to solve it after trying for a long time.

How to store a return value of a function in a variable?

I am trying to execute [iconv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html) function. And I have tried with this:

**my_var=$(iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 < sample-feed-utf16.xml > con_sample-feed-utf16.xml)**

The function executes, but the return value is not stored in `my_var`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `iconv` is not a function, it is an executable.  And what do you mean by "return value" -- the process's standard out/err, or its exit status?

Comment: Are you wanting the output to go into the variable, or the exit code?

Comment: @ephemient: I am trying to get the exit code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redirecting the output to a file, so nothing is going to go into the variable.

If you want to store the exit code, you can do it like this:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 < sample-feed-utf16.xml > con_sample-feed-utf16.xml
my_var=$?
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do:

```
my_var=$(shell command)
```

Then the standard output of the shell command will be stored in `my_var`. In your example, since you redirect the output of your shell command to a file, there is no output left to be stored in `my_var`.

Also, shell commands return an integer value (exit code) to the shell to indicate un/successful execution. You can store this value:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 < sample-feed-utf16.xml > con_sample-feed-utf16.xml
my_var=$?
[[ my_var -eq 0 ]] && echo success
```